# componentDidUpdate does not fire

Tags: react-redux

So I've been struggling to figure out the react-redux ecosystem for a while now. I'm almost there but there is still something that keep giving is me issues, and that's the componentDidUpdate method. When I dispatch an async action, the store is reducer is called correctly and the component's state does update.

But for some reason, the componentDidUpdate method does not fire, there is no re-render, and I cannot access the updated props. I can see it change in devtools, if I console.log(this.props.blogStore). At first it shows as an empty object but when on click it opens and shows the updated state.

I've tried as many life cycle methods as I can but nothing seems to work, including componentWillReceiveProps.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import App from './App';
import Datastore from 'Datastore';

const store = Datastore()

store.subscribe(() => console.log("state changed", store.getState()))

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**Datastore.js**

```
import { combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import Mainmenu from 'reducers/Mainmenu';
import Blogstore from 'reducers/Blogstore';

const reducer = combineReducers({
    Mainmenu,
    Blogstore,
})

export default function Datastore() {
    const store = createStore(
        reducer,
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    )

    return store
}
```

**reducer**

```
import Article from 'lib/Article';
import { ARTICLE_LOAD, ARTICLE_UPDATE, SAVE_ARTICLE_LIST } from 'actionTypes';

const initialBlogState = {
}

const Blogstore = (state=initialBlogState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SAVE_ARTICLE_LIST:
            state.init = true
            state.articles = action.payload
            return state
        case ARTICLE_LOAD:
            return state
        case ARTICLE_UPDATE:
            return state
    }
    return state
}

export default Blogstore;
```

**blog-actions.js**

```
import { ARTICLE_LOAD, ARTICLE_UPDATE, SAVE_ARTICLE_LIST } from 'actionTypes';
import APIFetch from '../lib/Fetch';

export function getArticlePids() {
    return dispatch => {
        APIFetch().get("/blog/list").then(response => {
            dispatch({
                type: SAVE_ARTICLE_LIST,
                payload: response.data
            })
        })
    }
}
```

**component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as blogActions from '../actions/blog-actions';

@connect(state => ({
    blogStore: state.Blogstore
}))
export default class Blog extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(blogActions.getArticlePids())
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        console.log("update", prevProps)
    }

    render() {
        console.log("render", this.props.blogStore)

        return (
            <div><h1>Blog</h1></div>
        )

    }
}
```

That is pretty much it. I won't bother pasting the App and Router that are between index.js and the component because there is nothing of interest there. Just a basic react router and components that have nothing to do with this.

Comment: I think the render function needs to return a different result in order for the reconciliation to detect changes: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

so on your return function you have to returns something like:

<div>{this.props.blogStore}</div> for it to work

Comment: Could you also post your reducer? Looks like you got side effect somewhere.

Comment: @Shota Sure, just included it in the code block. It's very barebones atm, since I'm simply just trying things out to try get it all to work.

Comment: @ospfranco Tried that but doesn't seem to do anything. I'm also trying to call this.forceUpdate() after the dispatch but I think it just re-renders the component before the promise finishes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to return a new object from your reducer, like this:

```
import Article from 'lib/Article';
import { ARTICLE_LOAD, ARTICLE_UPDATE, SAVE_ARTICLE_LIST } from 'actionTypes';

const initialBlogState = {
}

const Blogstore = (state=initialBlogState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SAVE_ARTICLE_LIST:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                init: true,
                articles: action.payload,
            })
        case ARTICLE_LOAD:
            return state
        case ARTICLE_UPDATE:
            return state
    }
    return state
}

export default Blogstore;
```

Otherwise, if you try to update your state directly (as you are doing currently) it will only mutate the internal reference of the state and react components won't be able to detect the change and wont re-render. [Read more here.](http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html#never-mutate-reducer-arguments)

Comment: Ahhh... okay now I see. I actually thought that's what I was doing. Enlightening read. Thank you, works great now.